# Overlay/fade in a div/text when hovering over an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an `<img>` that I want to be able to hover over, and when hovering over it I would be able to animate or fade in a div or text to display information of sorts. The information displayed will be overlaid on the image.
I've seen this done on a website before, I can't remember or place where I've seen it, but the idea is very clear in my mind.

I'm sorry I don't have any good attempts at this, I've read around and can't find anything that works for my idea.

I have not understood JS fully, but I can think of a few ideas to try and make it work. I just need a little help to get me in the right direction, before I try and do the rest by myself.

My first idea would be to remove the image directly, then replace it with a div that has that image in `background-image` with text overlaying it.

```js
document.getElementById("imageBox").onmouseover = function() {
    imageMouseOver()};
var image = document.getElementById("imageBox");
var textHere = imagine a lot of html here;
function imageMouseOver() {
    document.getElementById("imageBox").parentNode.removeChild(image);
    document.getElementById("imageBox").add(textHere);
};
```

The above doesn't work, and my other ideas would be based off of the initial one, for example:
-instead of removing the image, have the opacity of the image be reduced and something be added over it to simulate that effect
-or, have `opacity:0` to the actual overlay to hide it, and `onmouseover`, just make it appear with `opacity:1` and maybe `transition: opacity 200ms ease`?

Sorry I am asking too much here, but I'm pretty much clueless where to start, could someone point me somewhere for me to get started? Ideally a few examples would be good, or a site explaining it would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example with CSS using `:hover` to `transition` the `opacity` of your text element.

```css
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.text {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color: #fff;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em; bottom: 1em; left: 1em; right: 1em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.wrap:hover .text {
  opacity: 1;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
  <div class="text">text overlay</div>
</div>
```