# Fade in effect on image

Tags: css, hover, fadein

Hi I am trying to add a fade effect onto some images on a website I am making, I also want text to appear on the image when you hover over it. I have been googling and found tutorials saying you should use a class=overlay and class=text within a container and then reference to that in the css. I did this but it messed my whole format up and all my pictures moved. Should I add the overlay class into a separate div, if not how do I integrate it into my pre-existing code. Thanks!

```
<div id="image-wrap">
 <div class="image-column" id="col-1">
   <div class="image-container"><img src="images/piertopier.jpg.JPG"></div>
   <div class="image-container"><img src="images/lookingback.jpg.JPG"></div>
   <div class="image-container"><img src="images/heartshapedflocks.jpg.JPG></div>
 </div>
 <div class="image-column" id="col-2">
   <div class="image-container"><img src="images/twilight.jpg.JPG"></div>
   <div class="image-container"><img src="images/kindofblue.jpg.JPG"></div>
   <div class="image-container"><img src="images/palace.jpg.JPG"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="image-column" id="col-3">
   <div class="image-container"><img src="images/springtide.jpg.JPG"></div>
   <div class="image-container"><img src="images/medina.jpg.JPG"></div>
   <div class="image-container"><img src="images/stipple.jpg.JPG"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43302503/746736

Answer (score 0):

In your style sheet section add below style, to produce a hover fade effect

img:hover{opacity:0.5;transition:1ms;}

Change the values of opacity and transition as suited for you